# Bootstrap popover, hide on click outside? (Bootstrap ver 5.1.1)

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-popover

I need the following popover to work as follows; When user clicks within popover, it does not close. User clicks anywhere else on form, popover closes. Everything I've tried does not work. Please help!

```
$('#myAlerts').popover({
  "html": true,
  trigger: "manual",
  placement: "bottom",
  title: "Notifications",
  boundary: "viewport",
  fallbackPlacement: "flip",
  content: $('#alertsContainer')[0]
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  showAlerts();
}).click(function () {
  $(this).popover('toggle');
});
```